# why does an http post response add random characters at the end of response

Tags: c, http, post, webserver

I'm working on this web server and I have a minor problem. When the client sends a post request to my C web server, at the end, there are always random characters. The amount of random characters at the end varies but there are always characters at the end. I've tried to use the content-length header to make sure I only read a certain amount of bytes but this still doesn't fix it. This is an example of the responses i'm getting:

```
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Origin: http://localhost
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

rad1=on&rad2=on&rad3=on&rad4=on7
```

(I know this isn't the full request but I cut some of the request off for string manipulation reasons)

This is the code I have for reading the post response from the client:

```
readSock = read(acceptSock, recvLine, sizeof(recvLine)-1);
strcat(fullResp, recvLine);

if (readSock < 0) {
    printf("readSock error\n");

    memset(fileDir, 0, 255);
    memset(recvLineGET1, 0, 70);
    memset(httpResponseReport, 0, 1000);
    memset(recvLineGET, 0, 60);
    memset(fileLine, 0, 1);
    memset(httpResponse, 0, 1000);

    close(acceptSock);
    return NULL;
}


if ((endOfPost = strstr(fullResp, "\r\n\r\n")) != NULL) {

    postContentLength = strstr(fullResp, "Content-Length:");
    if (postContentLength != NULL) {
        strcpy(tempPost, postContentLength);

        finalPostLength = strchr(tempPost, ' ');

        contentLen = atoi(finalPostLength);
        printf("contentLength: %d\n", contentLen);


        char tempFull[contentLen];
        readSock = read(acceptSock, tempFull, sizeof(tempFull));
        strcat(fullResp, tempFull);
        printf("final: %s\n", fullResp);
    }
    if (strlen(endOfPost) > 4) {
        convertToDB(endOfPost);
    }
        

    printf("newline detected\n");
    break;
```

edit: I've debugged the program a bit more and found out that tempFull holds only part of the post data. Heres what i'm getting:

```
d3=on&rad4=onP*?
```

edit 2: I also found out that fullResp holds the first part of the response and that could be the reason i'm getting weird characters. Maybe its that i'm reading too much from the socket

Comment: We'll need a complete [mre] to answer fully but it's most likely that you are using strings which are not correctly NUL terminated. For example `readSock = read(acceptSock, tempFull, sizeof(tempFull));` does not result in a valid NUL terminated string in `tempFull`. It's ascii data but not a C string. You need to NUL terminate the buffer yourself.

Comment: @kaylum, how would i null terminate the string?

Comment: `tempFull[readSock] = '\0';`

Comment: @Barmar, but wouldn't read() just overwrite the null character? Also, I can't initialize a variable with a preset size.

Comment: You do this *after* `read()`, before calling `strcat()`.

Comment: Also, to leave room for this, you need to use `sizeof(tempFull)-1` in the `read()` call.

Comment: Oh okay. Let me try that.

Comment: Not relative to your issue, but never trust input from the outside, you cannot rely on content length you should set a max limit on it. imagine if the value is set to 2Go

Comment: @Barmar, didn't work

Comment: Review the rest of your code (which we can't see).

Comment: You have the same problem here: `readSock = read(acceptSock, recvLine, sizeof(recvLine)-1);`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I basically just copied everything to the fullResp variable then used strstr() to find the `\r\n\r\n` in fullResp, after that I copied only the amount specified by contentLen plus 4 into the final post body variable (plus 4 to read the `\r\n\r\n` and also read the full body).

this is the updated part that I added:

```
char tempFull[contentLen];
readSock = read(acceptSock, tempFull, sizeof(tempFull)-1);
strcat(fullResp, tempFull);
refindBody = strstr(fullResp, "\r\n\r\n");
strncpy(finalBody, refindBody, contentLen+4);

printf("finalBody: %s\n", finalBody);
```